# Array being inputted improperly from file

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, java.util.scanner

I am working on an RPG and I am storing my map files in a text file. When I import the values into the array, I get a random line of null values, and the rest of the non-null values have been shifted to the left.

I have tried restructuring my import method, but none of the modifications are working.

**Map File - spawn.map**

```
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,6,3,3,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,1,11,4,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,1,2,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,1,2,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,1,2,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,1,2,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,1,2,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,6,5,7,8,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,1,0,0,2,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,1,0,0,2,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,10,4,4,12,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14
```

**Import Method**

```java
package worldStuff;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class World {

    public static String[][] initWorld(String[][]array,String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        String string;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Resources/Map/"+name+".map"));
        input.useDelimiter(",|\\s+");
        while(j!=30) {
            string = input.next();
            array[j][i] = string;
            i++;
            if(i == 30) {
                i = 0;
                j++;
            }
        }
        input.close();
        return array;
    }

}
```

### This is the resulting array-

```
[[14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [6, 3, 3, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 1, 11, 4, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 1, 2, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 1, 2, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 1, 2, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 1, 2, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 1, 2, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 6, 5, 7, 8, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 1, 0, 0, 2, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 1, 0, 0, 2, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 10, 4, 4, 12, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14, 14],
 [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, , 14]]
```

[image: Ingame Picture]

Comment: does each line contain the same number of elements? if so, I'd read line by line and process each line separately. Also, this aren't `null` values but empty strings, right? Most likely because of line breaks handled by your delimiter regex. This would be avoided if you compute it line-wise without a scanner. you could just process a line fill the row in the array and so on and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, empty value is carriage return character in end each line.
you can add check to your code

```java
if (isBlank(string)) {
 continue;
}
```

or use

```java
array[j] = input.nextLine().split(',');
```